Prevent content from expanding parent's width having `flex: 1`
I have the following html layout, where I want to give a fixed width to the first and third divs, while making the second div take the remaining width.
Normally, this can be achieved by giving flex: 1 to the second div, however, if this div has a big content, it will make it grow further, and shrink the "fixed" width of the first and third containers.
<div class="container">
  <div class="child-small"></div>
  <div class="child-big">
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
  </div>
  <div class="child-small"></div>
</div>

<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .child-small {
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    outline: 1px solid green;
  }

  .child-big {
    flex: 1;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
  }
</style>

I was expecting the first and the third containers to always respect their fixed width, i.e., was expecting the second div to not expand horizontally, but rather vertically.

I think adding word-break: break-all CSS-Style to your class named container does some work. Moreover, height:100% is to be set replacing height:"100%", Remove those quotes.

min-width: 0 on that element
